# Show that if $A$ is any square matrix such that $A^n = 0$ for some positive intiger $n$, then $A$ is not invertible. (answer check)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, formal-proofs

Show that if $A$ is any square matrix such that $A^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$, then $A$ is not invertible.

I'm not sure if my proof is good enough, or enough "work" as my teacher put it after my last test.

This is what I have:

$$A^n = 0$$

or $A$ to be invertible, 
$$A^n  A^{-n}  = I$$

Then:

$$A^{n} \cdot A^{n} =0 \cdot A^{-n} $$

$$I \neq 0$$

this is not true, so $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: that should be a bold 0, signifying the 0 matrix i guess.

Comment: Yeah that's good, I mean maybe you should explicitly show that if $A$ is invertible then $A^nA^{-n}=1$ though.

Comment: thats a good point

Comment: This is one of those statements where one must make an exception for $0\times0$ matrices: $I_0=0$ is actually true, and $A^n=0$ (trivially true for $0\times0$ matrices) does not imply that $A$ is non-invertible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0=det(A^n)=(det(A))^n \implies det(A)=0$ thus $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Nooooo!! I mean technically correct, but this problem is so much more simple than the need for determinants.

Comment: yes it is , but I was just providing an alternate

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:If  $A$  is nilpotent operator, then its only eigenvalue is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this: If $n$ is the small natural number such that $A^n=0,$ then let $v$ be such that $A^{n-1}v\ne 0,$ then $A(A^{n-1}v)=0$ and  so $A$ isn't invertible.